# Export several dataframes to several Excel files

Tags: r

I tried to export several data frames to different Excel files. However it doesn't work properly.

I used the package xlsx and write.xlsx using a loop.

```r
data_frame_list <-list(df1,df2)
path<-'./OUTPUT/'

for (i in data_frame_list){write.xlsx(i, paste0(path,i, '.xlsx'))}
```

I would like to obtain two files : df1.xlsx and df2.xlsx stored in the folder OUTPUT.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try `for (i in 1:length(data_frame_list)){write.xlsx(data_frame_list[[i]], paste0(path,"df",i, '.xlsx'))}` - your problem is the `i` in your paste statement, which is a whole dataframe, not just the name of one!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It doesn't work I obtained two files 1.xlsx and 2.xlsx without data Inside